# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 due to declaration

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to run my code in xcode 8(swift 3.0). When I uncomment this line

```
var arrMovie:[Dictionary]?
```

I am able to run the app.Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: better to use pure swift approach I think

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is a generic type, it requires two arguments; the key and value.

```
var arrMovie: [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]?
```